# Customize adb prompt

Tags: android, adb

How can I reduce the length of the path printed before the prompt of the shell opened by `adb shell`? My problem is that it is so long that I can no longer see my commands because the doesn't break the line automatically. I would prefer something like the name of the current directory or an abstract code example.

`sh -v` on Android phone gives me

```
# Copyright (c) 2010
#   Thorsten Glaser <t.glaser@tarent.de>
# This file is provided under the same terms as mksh.
#-
# Minimal /system/etc/mkshrc for Android

: ${TERM:=vt100} ${HOME:=/data} ${MKSH:=/system/bin/sh} ${HOSTNAME:=android}
: ${SHELL:=$MKSH} ${USER:=$(typeset x=$(id); x=${x#*\(}; print -r -- ${x%%\)*})}
if (( USER_ID )); then PS1='$'; else PS1='#'; fi
function precmd {
    typeset e=$?

    (( e )) && print -n "$e|"
}
PS1='$(precmd)$USER@$HOSTNAME:${PWD:-?} '"$PS1 "
export HOME HOSTNAME MKSH PS1 SHELL TERM USER
alias l='ls'
alias la='l -a'
alias ll='l -l'
alias lo='l -a -l'

for p in ~/.bin; do
    [[ -d $p/. ]] || continue
    [[ :$PATH: = *:$p:* ]] || PATH=$p:$PATH
done

unset p

: place customisations above this line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change your PS1 prompt to be something smaller with the line:

```
PS1="> "
```

but it'd probably be better to instead increase the width of your window with something like:

```
COLUMNS=150
```

Comment: Thanks! The changes take place in the file `/system/etc/mkshrc` (don't forget to `mount -o remout,rw /system`) and the output of `sh -v` is not reliable for changes - only the file content :)